# Using Youtube videos of any channel in my app with YoutubeApiPlayer is Legal

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I am using youtube api player jar file in my app. Is it Legal to use any video from youtube of any channel without permission of owner of that channel in my app for public use
Can you please help me to deal with this question.

**Any anwers are highly appreciated**

Comment: If you use the youtube api then it is perfectly legal. Whatever is illegal will be automatically blocked by utube according to location

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply fetching a video from youtube, then, in theory, it should still use Youtube's servers. That means it should be perfectly fine.

Comment: I am using that video for my profit in my app from youtube of unknown channel without permission of owner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this videos **BUT you cannot play them in background** .